# Pick a single face from a mesh in X3DOM

Tags: x3d, x3dom

there are examples in official X3DOM website about picking objects, but cannot find any examples there on how to pick a single face from a mesh. Anyone here know how to do? Also is there any solutions to draw the wireframe and face at the same time? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "pick a single face"? Drawing the wireframe and the faces at the same time is up to the program used for the visualisation

Comment: "pick a single face" means coloring a triangle with another color after clicking on it, and may also give the index of the triangle. Thanks!